# Struts redirection

Tags: redirect, struts2

I have one abc.jsp page.
I have an image on that page.
On clicking that image, I need to check for user already logged in or not.
If yes, I need to display xyz.jsp.
If not, I need to ask the user to login.
On success, again I need to go to xyz.jsp.

I am using Struts2.

Help me in this issue.

Comment: please show your abc.jsp page

Comment: It has an image, and some other stuff.

Comment: Creating an Interceptor is the right way

Comment: Okay, i have done using interceptor and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use interceptors for your purpose. Interceptors will help you to perform tasks like authentication check, logging..etc before and after each request.
Following link will may be useful for you to implement authentication in struts2.

http://www.journaldev.com/2210/struts-2-interceptor-tutorial-with-custom-authentication-interceptor-example

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple steps(Without interceptor):

1) Define action in struts.xml file :

```
<action name="CheckUserDtl"
            class="com.user.CheckUserDtl">
            <result>/WEB-INF/user/xyz.jsp</result>
</action>
```

2) in your abc.html page- onclick of image button call **CheckuserDtl** action

3) Write your authentication code in `com.user.CheckUserDtl` action file:

Example :

```
@Override
    public String execute()
    {

        //write code authentication code here
        return SUCCESS;

    }
```

**Note**: Better way is to use **interceptors** for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have used interceptor concept to solve this question.